# I created two tables try to create foreign key for the second in first, it doesn't work, but I am able to get when I create it from second why?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

> > the first table 'A' consists of refid(primary key), name, gender, age, status the second table 'b' consists of refid(primary key) and statename, when I write the query in table A to refer B it doesn't works, but it worked when I try it from the table B
> >     1)why I am not able to access from table A?

2) I want to know what is the difference between referencing it from A and referencing it from B?

```
          ALTER TABLE A
         ADD FOREIGN KEY (refId)
         REFERENCES B(refId)

         // it doesn't work

         ALTER TABLE B
         ADD FOREIGN KEY (refId)
         REFERENCES A(refId)

         // it works
```

By "not working", I mean that I get an error from the foreign key:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(testdrive.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-4b8_8d'>, CONSTRAINT
#sql-4b8_8d_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (refid) REFERENCES reserve (refid))
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an explanation

Comment: @zerkms I mean its not working when I refer it from A, but it works when I refer it from B, and I don't know the difference between referring the table B from A and A from B

Comment: still explains nothing. What "its not working when..." means?

Answer (score 1):

You say that you're getting a

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

error when you have an FK from `A.refid` to `B.refid`:

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD FOREIGN KEY (refId)
REFERENCES B(refId)
```

Foreign keys are used to maintain referential integrity so if you have an FK from `A.refid` to `B.refid`, then you can't insert `refid=X` into `A` unless `refid=X` is already in `B`. The error message is telling you that you're trying to insert (or update) a `refid` value in `A` that is not in `B`, for example:

```
insert into A (refid) values (1);
insert into B (refid) values (1);
```

If you reverse the FK to point from `B.refid` to `A.refid` then the above INSERT sequence will work. Or, you could reverse the INSERTs:

```
insert into B (refid) values (1);
insert into A (refid) values (1);
```

so that the foreign key will not be violated.